# How to decrease health when you collide with specific game object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So, I did some experimenting. But this part of code doesn't work, it doesn't decrease health but there's no any compiler error.

Not working part:

```
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.name == "Bullet")
        {
            
            
            TakeDamage(20);
            Debug.Log("Damaged!");

            if (currentHealth <= 0f)
            {
                SceneManager.LoadScene("You Lost!");
            }
        }
    }
```

So simply, there's an ai that shoots bullet, which is the bullet is an game object. The game object "bullet' has "isTrigger" enabled, I also tried to disable the is trigger thing. But after experimenting a lot of times, it doesn't works and can't be fixed. How do I fix it?

Here's the entire code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class PlayerHealth : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int maxHealth = 100;
    public int currentHealth;

    public HealthBar healthBar;

    void Start()
    {
        currentHealth = maxHealth;
        healthBar.SetMaxHealth(maxHealth);
    }

    private void OnCollisionStay(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.name == "Bullet(Clone)")
        {
            
            
            TakeDamage(20);
            Debug.Log("Damaged!");

            if (currentHealth <= 0f)
            {
                SceneManager.LoadScene("You Lose!");
            }
        }
    }

    void TakeDamage(int damage)
    {
        currentHealth -= damage;

        healthBar.SetHealth(currentHealth);
    }
}
```

I tried adding "Update()", I was expecting the health to get updated and get damaged but did not work ([{bruhhh}]).

Comment: Does either object have a Rigidbody?

Comment: the object have rigidbody on, the ai won't work if the rigidbody is disabled

Comment: There are still parts of the configuration that aren't entirely clear. Here are a few questions to narrow it down: Do both objects have a collider? Is the bullet being moved by setting the velocity of the rigidbody, or by setting the position of the transform? Are the bullet and the player on layers that are not set to physically interact? Where in the hierarchy is the PlayerHealth component relative to the player's collider? Are the rigidbodies of either the player or bullet marked as kinematic? If the bullet moves more slowly, does a collision occur?

Comment: In general `The game object "bullet' has "isTrigger" enabled` -> then there won't be any collision and `OnCollisionXY` won't be called but only `OnTriggerXY` .. see [Collision Action Matrix](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html)

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to have a enabled rigidbody on one of the objects. (Check if `OnCollisionStay()` has to be a 2D or your collider or something)
2. They both need to have enabled colliders
3. Also you're checking name of the object, if this AI is creating these bullet*s* they are not named "Bullet," they are named "Bullet (1)" and so on.
4. If the bullets are fast moving objects you might need to have your rigidbody on [collisionDetectionMode](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-collisionDetectionMode.html).

If it's the name thing. just add a tag to your "shootable objects" and check `if(collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Shootable"))` on their collision detection.